# How to make a complete matrix with 2 loops in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, transform

I have a string in c++ and it represents an upper triangular matrix, What I want to do is meake a complete matrix from this string

```
    std::string input = "1,2,1,3,6,1,4,7,9,1";
    //this represents


 //1  2  3 4
 //2  1  6 7
 //3  6  1 9
 //4  7  9 1

std::replace(input.begin(), input.end(), ',', ' ');
std::vector<double> Matrix;
std::istringstream inputStream(input);
double value;
int rowNum = 0;
int colNum = 0; 

while (inputStream >> value){
    for (colNum = 0; colNum < 2; colNum++){
        if (colNum >= rowNum){
            Matrix.push_back( value ); 
        }
        else{
            Matrix.push_back( Matrix[colNum * 2 + rowNum]); 
        }
    }

    rowNum++;
}
inputStream >> std::ws;
```

Instead of getting

```
 1  2  3 4
 2  1  6 7
 3  6  1 9
 4  7  9 1
```

But I am getting

```
   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   2.0000
   1.0000   1.0000   2.0000   1.0000
   1.0000   2.0000   1.0000   1.0000
   2.0000   1.0000   1.0000   2.0000
```

What is it my error? I can not see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show the indexing scheme used for printing the output (i.e. how do you expect the indexes works): your choice of using a vector instead of a matrix make hard to correct the code. For sure, I see the following points that have no clear connection with the input pattern:

1) each number you read you increment the rowNum index. The row should be incremented instead at 'steps' 1, 1+2, 1+2+3,...

2) colNum should range from 0 to current rowNum, instead assumes just 0,1

3) there is no chance to fill a row (say the first) before you read (say the last). You could do if the input would be 1 2 3 4 1 6 7 1 9 1

all these points are related, and origin from the wrong data representation, that make difficult a trivial task.

In C++, a very effective way to tackle these problems is data hiding: consider how easily we can write a class that gives the correct logical representation and doesn't waste space:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T = double>
class upper_triangular_matrix
{
    std::vector<T> Matrix;

public:

    upper_triangular_matrix(std::string input)
    {
        // trade time for space: store the values, compute indexing
        std::replace(input.begin(), input.end(), ',', ' ');
        std::istringstream inputStream(input);
        T value;
        while (inputStream >> value)
            Matrix.push_back(value);

        // validate size: ok 1,1+2,1+2+3 etc
    }

    T operator()(int r, int c) const
    {
        // compute indexing accounting for miss duplicated
        if (c > r)
            std::swap(c, r);
        int p = 0, n = 1;
        while (r > 0)
        {
            p += n++;
            r--;
        }
        return Matrix[p + c];
    }
};

int main()
{
    upper_triangular_matrix<> m("1,2,1,3,6,1,4,7,9,1");
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
            std::cout << m(r, c) << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

when run, this prints

```
1 2 3 4 
2 1 6 7 
3 6 1 9 
4 7 9 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly where the error is but here is where it starts:

```
std::vector<double> Matrix;
```

Yes, a non-empty `std::vector<double>` with `n` elements is a matrix: either a 1xn or a nx1 matrix (or both). In your context this view is, however, utterly unhelpful.

Let's look at the `for`-loop when you read the first element:

1. colNum == 0, rowNum == 0 => (1, 1) = Matrix[0] = 1
2. colNum == 1, rowNum == 0 => (2, 1) = Matrix[1] = 1

This start is clearly wrong. After this `rowNum` becomes 1:

1. colNum == 0, rowNum == 1 => (3, 1) = Matrix[2] = Matrix[colNum * 2 + rowNum] = Matrix[1] = 1
2. colNum == 1, rowNum == 1 => (4, 1) = Matrix[3] = 2

Well, I guess you can write the remainder up yourself. Of course, I could quickly write the code to solve your problem but I think this little exercise is for you. The way to do it is to fill the first `row` columns (where `row` is the current row being processed, using conventional index starting with `0`) with the values from the transposed matrix and then read the remaining `n - row` columns (where `n` is the size of the matrix) from the file.

Comment: so the first thing is change for loop `for (colNum = 0; colNum < 4; colNum++){` to 4, so it does the thing 4 times for the columns